# What is this plant with serrated leaves?

Tags: identification

[image]

Any one can recognize this plant?

Comment: Might be a dahlia, but it could be a Chrysanthemum, can you take a photo a little further back to show some more of the plant please, especially any buds, open flowers and preferably some spent flowerheads as well as leaves

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure it's a dahlia but it's one plant I never bothered growing.

[image: Leaf] 
Photo of a typical leaf.

[image: Bud]
And a dahlia bud starting to open as yours is.